# Remove feature from featureCollection turf.js

Tags: javascript, geospatial, geojson, turfjs

I have a `featureCollection`. Each element has `properties` which again has the entry `arr`. `arr` either contains `[]`, or `["a",.... n]`. I want to remove every element from the `featureCollection` where `arr.length !== 0`.

How would I do that in `turf.js` (version 5.1.6)?
Is there a inherent function for that? Or would I have to use simple `dict` mutation, native to `JS`?

Comment: Not sure about turf, but you can do `featureCollection = featureCollection.filter(function(feature){ return feature.arr.length === 0 })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of v5.1.6 of TurfJS there is no function for filtering featureCollections by feature properties in TurfJS.

For this sort of thing just use native javascript functions like [array filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as suggested by @Rajesh.

```
var matchingFeatures = featureCollection.features.filter(function (feature){ 
   return feature.properties.arr.length === 0 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively achieve this using `featureReduce` and `featureCollection` (from `@turf/meta` and `@turf/helpers`)

```
  Feature,
  Geometries,
  Properties,
  featureCollection,
} from "@turf/helpers";
import { featureReduce } from "@turf/meta";

export function filterGeo(input: any, func: (feature: any) => boolean): any {
  featureCollection(
    featureReduce(
      input,
      (arr, cur) => {
        if (func(cur)) {
          arr.push(cur);
        }
        return arr;
      },
      [] as Array<Feature<Geometries, Properties>>
    )
  );
}

const filtered = filterGeo(featureCollection, feature => (
  feature.properties.arr.length === 0
));
```